# Building a report with formatting

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I am utilizing a background server connected to a GUI Flask application (both coded in python) to serve up report based information.  My report will have rows of information with columns of years.

I would like to keep the GUI as independent of the background reports as possible, to keep the report development burden on the server.

The problem I am faced with is how to incorporate the format of the information in the report rows so that the GUI can represent the information appropriately.  I share a report example below:

```
          2020     2019     2018
Sales   $1,000   $1,300   $1,052
Growth    -23%      24%       --
```

Passing the data to the GUI would be managed with a dataframe / pysql process.  Flask will of course be utilizing an html format.  If the format was confined to the columns, I could use dataframe formatting to codify, but the variant display formats are occurring in the rows.

I will be grateful for any thoughts on how I might approach this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't want to return data as one string with the whitespacing (line breaks etc) used above, one of the most common approaches to returning data from a server to be consumed by a client/GUI is to use XML or JSON. JSON's probably sufficient, and Python has [a built-in module for converting dictionaries and lists to JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). If you're working with Pandas, it also has [built-in JSON decoders](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Can json store a format with it?

Comment: As in, some instructions for the GUI? You can put whatever you want in there (e.g. "--" for a 0 value), but usually the formatting is the responsibility of the GUI.  Like, how many decimal places to display, date formatting, etc. This should give you more flexibility, but you don't have to be doctrinaire about it. If you tell Pandas to convert a column to a string, and re-format the values (`0.24` -> `'24%'`) because it's easier/faster to help you get an MVP out, that's not the end of the world.

Comment: Interesting...I hadn't thought of doing a conversion to strings.  This would be an effective solution.  thank you.